# Getting error "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" when trying to sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download all the available files from my s3 bucket to my local machine. I have installed AWS cli. and then I have used aws configure to setup access key and secret key too. I am facing issue while trying to execute the following command:

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://tempobjects .
```

Setup commands

```
LAMU02XRK97:s3 vsing$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*******kHXE
LAMU02XRK97:s3 vsing$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=******Ssv

LAMU02XRK97:s3 vsing$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************kHXE shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************pSsv shared-credentials-file    
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

Error:

```
LAMU02XRK97:s3 vsing$ aws s3 sync s3://tempobjects .
fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Comment: I'd suggest the obvious - make sure access key id and secret access key are valid. At least the suffix `kHXE` in you access key id suggest that something's wrong, acess key ids are normally uppercase.

Comment: access_key id is uppercase only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have replicated the scenario and to make it work you need to make sure that the user you are using for CLI is having the same access keys configured in the IAM.

Below is what configured in AWS CLI.

[image]

Below is what configured in AWS IAM for the same user :

[image]

Access Key ending with QYHP is configured at both the places and hence it is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you! So I am not the one who created/own this access key and secret key. I am just trying to use my team members keys for a separate effort on my machine. I checked with him and he is saying that these keys are valid. Are you saying that in order to use someone else's keys, I need to do something additional on my machine?

Comment: @vsingh No, you don't need anything additional. You only need access key id and the secret key. My bet is that keys you've been provided is are invalid.

Comment: Now my next challenge is to download based on modified date or any other way to download images faster as I got millions of images on my s3 bucket